# Change date formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need a macro to change the date and time formatting in Word

From:
[11:47, 9/21/2017]

To:
21/09/2017, 11:47 -

I have a document with over 9000 lines that need changing.  Is this even possible?  I have read a few things that allow me to change the date, but nothing that allows me to change the date and time.

What I have so far:

```
Sub GetDateAndReplace()
Dim FoundOne As Boolean

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
FoundOne = True ' loop at least once

Do While FoundOne ' loop until no date is found
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "([0-9]{2,2})[:]([0-9]{2,2})[,]([0-9]{1,2})[/]([0-9]{1,2})[/]([0-9]{4})"
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceNone

    ' check the find to be sure it's a date
    If IsDate(Selection.Text) Then
        Selection.Text = Format(Selection.Text, " dd/mm/yyyy, hh:mm")
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Else ' not a date - end loop
        FoundOne = False
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

But I get this error

> Run-time error '6003': The Find What text contains a Pattern Match
> expression which is too complex.

Comment: Use a simpler search e.g. the find text should be "(\[)(*)(\])".

Comment: this didn't work, I know the search is simpler but it throws IsDate off.

Comment: The found range will now include the [ and ] so these need to be removed before you use IsDate.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need all those parentheses & grouping brackets around the expressions. You don't really even need a macro, either. Try three `wildcard` Find/Replace operations, where:

```
Find = ([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}, )([0-9]/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4})
Replace = \10\2
Find = ([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}, [0-9]{2}/)([0-9]/[0-9]{4})
Replace = \10\2
Find = ([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}), ([0-9]{2}/)([0-9]{2}/)([0-9]{4})
Replace = \3\2\4, \1
```

**Note:** If you're using non-English regional date settings, you'll need to change {1,2} to {1;2}.

If you really want a macro, you could use:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}, )([0-9]/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4})"
    .Replacement.Text = "\10\2"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}, [0-9]{2}/)([0-9]/[0-9]{4})"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}), ([0-9]{2}/)([0-9]{2}/)([0-9]{4})"
    .Replacement.Text = "\3\2\4, \1"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This almost works.  Firstly changing the {1,2} to {1;2} generates an error saying that the expression isn't valid.  I do need to swap the dates do that they change from MM/DD/YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY.  But also this solution doesn't work for prepending a zero.  A date like 2/3/2017 needs to become 03/02/2017

Comment: @rxssmcdxwell: Answer updated with macro for prepending 0s.

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit more investigation and found a limnitation of the find/replace in Word (I'm using Office 365, Word 2016).

The previous answer missed the fact that you are also transposing within the date.

When I built the find query in which the date is also transposed as required I got

"([)(*)(,)( @)(*)(/)(*)(/)(*)(])"

but it wouldn't work, giving the same error you reported.  After a little more investigation it seems that this is due to a limit of 9 on the number of find fields.

Given text of 123456789A then a search for

"(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)"

works fine but

"(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)(A)"

fails.

In your particular case we can reduce the number of find fields to 9 by changing (,) to just , giving a find query of

"([)(*),( @)(*)(/)(*)(/)(*)(])"

This means that you can now rebuild the date with a replace instruction of

"\6//\4//\8, \1 -"

If you weren't able to simplify your search to 9 find fields or less you would need to do multiple searches.  In your case the first would be to transpose the time and date using the find  /replace presented in the previous answer and the second to transpose within the date.

As an aside if you can't guarantee that there are always one or more spaces after the comma you should do an initial find/replace to add a space after the comma.  This is because there is no find field that works on 0 or more characters and the proposed find query will work with one or more spaces but not when there are no spaces.

You will note that in my find query I didn't look for numbers, just the separators.  This means the Find/Replace will work equally well with dates that have month names rather than month numbers e.g. 21/Sep/2017.

If you did want a programatic solution then I would suggest avoiding the use of find/replace and instead use the range movewhile/moveuntil methods because you have a well defined field bounded by the [ and ].  You could then use the VBA function split to create two arrays from the range text.  The first would split the string into time and date by splitting at the ',' and the second split to get the date into day,month, year by splitting at the '/'